# Generalize a claim in a structural induction proof to be able to use the induction hypothesis

Tags: isabelle, induction

I want to prove the following

```
lemma
  fixes pi :: "'a path" and T :: "'a ts"
  shows "valid_path T pi s ⟹ ∀ op ∈ set pi. valid_operator T op"
```

by induction on pi where

```
fun valid_path :: "'a ts ⇒ 'a path ⇒ 'a state ⇒ bool" where
"valid_path T [] s = True" |
"valid_path T (op#ops) s = (valid_operator T op ∧ valid_path T ops (effect op s))
```

and path is just a type synonym for an operator list.
The other definitions should not play a role for the proof.

The base case works fine.

The problem is that, informally, for the inductive step where `pi = (x # xs)` I'm assuming that

```
if valid_path T xs s
then ∀ op ∈ set xs. valid_operator T op
```

and I must show that this implies

```
if valid_path T (x#xs) s
then ∀ op ∈ set (x#xs). valid_operator T op
```

I can use the definition of `valid_path` here, so this last expression is equivalent to

```
if valid_path T (xs) (effect x s)
then ∀ op ∈ set (x#xs). valid_operator T op
```

If I could be able to use the induction hypothesis on `valid_path T (xs) (effect x s)` I would be done.

I can't since the hypothesis only holds for `valid_path T (xs) s` instead of `valid_path T xs (effect x s)`.

But this does not really matter since the predicate of that if statement does not depend on `s` at all!

But Isabelle does not know that so it complains.

How can I make it such that I can apply the inductive hypothesis on `valid_path T (xs) (effect x s)`?
I have a feeling that I have to make the claim more general, so that I can use the hypothesis on the proof, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very common that you have to generalize some terms in an induction. Use the keyword `arbitrary` in the induct method.

```
proof (induct pi arbitrary: s)
```

This is explained in Chapter 2.4 of [Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2019/doc/prog-prove.pdf).